# How to winterize pipe to outdoor hose bib if the valve is lower than the outdoor bib

Tags: valve, kitchen-sink, hose

I've recently bought a house and am not able to contact the previous owner. I'm trying to winterize the house for the upcoming winter in New Jersey. I have an outdoor hose bib but the only valve I can find to turn it off is located under my kitchen sink. There is quite a lot of space between the kitchen sink and the outdoor hose bib, at least 15 feet. I'm not sure if the pipe is inside or outside, its not visible but it could be under the vinyl siding.

I don't see anywhere obvious to drain or blowout the pipe, so I'm looking for suggestions on whether I need to do anything, or if it will be ok to leave as is. The higher portion of the pipe leads to the kitchen faucet[image: The]

[image: The Valve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the outside faucet and shut off the valve under the kitchen sink. Make sure that stops the water from flowing outside and then leave the outside faucet open for the winter.

This accomplishes two things, first it establishes that the valve under the sink is indeed the cutoff for the hose bib, and second, leaving the hose bib open will prevent any residual water from being trapped in the cold part of the pipe and freezing in there.

It's not likely that the pipe is tucked under the siding, but even if it is, evacuating the water will prevent freeze damage.

In the spring, do the procedure in reverse.

Comment: I have done the steps above, my concern is that since the cut-off valve is lower, gravity will keep some water in the pipe.

Comment: It might. but as long as the water isn't restrained in the pipe (the outdoor valve is open) it shouldn't be able to build up enough pressure to damage the plumbing if it freezes. Also, the water (if any) will collect in the lowest portion of the pipe, which you indicated is at the inside valve which is inside a heated environment. You might want to check again to confirm that the outdoor bib is higher than the indoor cut-off. That would be a very unusual arrangement.

Comment: I've checked again, this certainly cuts off the flow outside but I can't find any other valves at a higher level.

Comment: OK You should be all set then.

Comment: Just a follow up that the pipe survived winter ok just being left open with the water cut off.

Answer (score 1):

See if there is a knurled drain plug on the shut off valve (see picture).  After turning off the water and opening the faucet, remove the drain plug.

[image]

Comment: "remove the drain plug" - First put a container below the valve!

Comment: That goes without saying, @whatsisname. However, it often needs to be said.

Comment: unfortunately this is not the case.